# Seaborn will not import in Jupyter notebook

Tags: import, anaconda, seaborn, jupyter, importerror

I just used used the Seaborn library about 5 days ago, no problems.
Tried to use it yesterday and it's giving an error when I try to import. Someone about a year ago had the same exact problem but their fix did not work for me. I'm trying to complete a project and this is a huge set back so if anyone can help, please do!

**input**

```
import seaborn as sns
```

**result**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a84c0541e888> in <module>
----> 1 import seaborn as sns

/opt/anaconda3/envs/datascience/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/__init__.py in <module>
      8 from .palettes import *
      9 from .linearmodels import *
---> 10 from .categorical import *
     11 from .distributions import *
     12 from .timeseries import *

/opt/anaconda3/envs/datascience/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in <module>
      5 from scipy import stats
      6 import pandas as pd
----> 7 from pandas.core.series import remove_na
      8 import matplotlib as mpl
      9 from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

ImportError: cannot import name 'remove_na'
```